# What's the best way to reference examples?

Tags: cross-referencing

I am writing a programming book on AWK in Latex and I have hundreds of code examples, for example,

```
awk '1; { print "" }'
```

I am curious how can I reference the example later in the book. At the current stage it's example #3, but if I add one before it, I'd like the numbering to update automatically, and I'd also like to make a clickable link in the final pdf, that would bring the user to the example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You will probably want to use a package to help with pretty-printing the code snippets. Two popular choices for the job are the [listings](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) and [minted](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted) packages.

Both packages provide a `listing` environment that can be cross-referenced similar to a table, figure or equation. The names of all listings used in your document can also be gathered together in a big list using `\listoflistings`, similar to a table of contents.

See the package documentation for more details.

Comment: And then if you want to make it fancy, `tocloft` can improve LoL just like it can improve ToC.

Comment: @Peteris: `minted` should work on Windows if you install Pygments. Some people report installing it successfully. Can't say I've tried it though.

Comment: @Petris You just need to install Python and `Pygments`. Just make sure that the environment variables `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` are set correctly. Admittedly, not as easy of a job as on UNIX-like systems.

Answer (score 0):

In short you tag a reference with

```
\ref{type:Name}
```

and you reference that tag with

```
\label{type:Name}
```

For more info have a look at the appropriate page at the [wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing). There are also more specialized packages for referencing, but the concept is always the same.

As you have hundreds of examples, try to find a suitable, naming convention for your examples.

### Update

For inter-document linking check the [hypperef](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Hyperref) package